# How to move OneNote files from OneDrive to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, onedrive

I have around 20 OneNote files which are my personal reference. It contains almost 10 years of data. I recently got the unlimited space in Google Drive.

Now I would like to move all my OneDrive to Google Drive without any file loss.

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this safely?

Comment: download them from OneDrive and upload them to Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

1. go to **https://onedrive.live.com/?id=root**
2. select your OneNote files
3. download them to your desktop
   [image]
4. go to **https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive**
5. press that **+** sign
6. select **File upload**
   [image]
7. choose your file and upload them
8. wait a bit and you are done

---

apart of this transfer above, you can also use a website tool like:

- **https://www.cloudhq.net/synch_wizard**
- and here is tutorial: **https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-sync-onedrive-and-google-drive/**

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to share all your files in OneDrive and save the shared files in Google Drive. 
Also, just as user0 said, a third party tool can help you directly [copy all files from OneDrive to GDrive](https://www.multcloud.com/tutorials/copy-from-onedrive-to-google-drive-3889.html) like cloudHQ. Yet, i'm used to another one called MultCloud.